# Paypal integration of javascript button with redirection to download link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, paypal

I'm using the Javascript button for paypal integration in my website,

```
<script data-amount="{{x.price}}"data-callback="abc.com/myProjects" data-return="abc.com/myProjects" data-currency="USD" data-quantity="1" data-name="{{x.a}}"data-number="{{x.id}}" data-button="paynow" src="resources/paypal-button.min.js? merchant=abc@xyz.com" async="async"></script>
```

Here, I'm using AngularJS to pass name price and id,
now i want to redirect the user after successful transaction to a page where he can download the item he paid for, more like a my downloads section where i can download that particular item.
I think it's to do something with data-callback or data-return parameter. Any leads on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the download URL in data-return parameter, then PayPal return to the download page to let buyer to download specific item.

Comment: as i specified i want to redirect him to a My downloads page where he can find his article, but how do i track the article? like track that he has paid for that article only.

Comment: You need to enable PDT feature, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/?mark=PDT PayPal will send transaction detail to your return URL, after you receive the transaction detail, you can write script to show specific item download.